# Fetching random items from each Model in a collection in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, random, model

I've a data that looks something like

```
var categories = [
    {
        name: 'Animals',
        img: 'animals.jpg',
        list: [{name: 'Cat', img: 'cat.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Dog', img: 'dog.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Zebra', img: 'zebra.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Rabbit', img: 'rabbit.jpg', state: 'hidden'}]
    },
    {
        name: 'Birds',
        img: 'birds.jpg',
        list: [{name: 'Eagle', img: 'eagle.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Owl', img: 'owl.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Parrot', img: 'parrot.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Swan', img: 'swan.jpg', state: 'hidden'}]
    },
    {
        name: 'Fruits',
        img: 'fruits.jpg',
        list: [{name: 'Apple', img: 'apple.jpg', state: 'hidden'},{name: 'Cherry', img: 'cherry.jpg', state: 'hidden'},{name: 'Banana', img: 'banana.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Strawberry', img: 'strawberry.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Mango', img: 'mango.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Orange', img: 'orange.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Pomegranate', img: 'pomegranate.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Jackfruit', img: 'jackfruit.jpg', state: 'hidden'}]
    },
    {
        name: 'Flowers',
        img: 'flowers.jpg',
        list: [{name: 'Rose', img: 'rose.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Tulip', img: 'tulip.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Hibiscus', img:'hibiscus.jpg', state: 'hidden'}, {name: 'Sunflower', img: 'sunflower.jpg', state: 'hidden'}]
    }
    ];
```

Here I'm using the categories as Collection and each category as a Model. What I want is to get a random set of objects from this collection, which are in the list of each Model. Say if I click random I might get a list of Jackfruit, Rose, Apple, Eagle, Cat, Tulip.

Not too sure if the structure I created is right. Should I use a model for each item in the object list array of each category?

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number or how to use that random number to index into a collection?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case where in many factors come into play.

If the models are static or dynamic. It might be easy for the former case. Wherein you would be needing to know the range of id's or cid's of all the models in your collection.

**Static case**

Store all the id's in an array . Select a random index of the array using Math.random().

Then you can use this

```
collection.get( arr[Math.random() * arr.length()]);
```

Think this might be a overkill but it is difficult to say a better approach without knowing the source or range of data.

Comment: Sorry, the question was wrongly framed. I've edited it again.